# caching object in DOM vs javascript variable

Tags: javascript, json, caching, dom

I've recently looked at some front end js code.

(1) In some cases the code creates a new JavaScript object from a JSON received from the back end. Then the newly created object is stored in a cache (say a map). This way the object would be cached on the front end for later use.

(2) I've also seen instances when the new JavaScript object (called `eventObject` here) is stored in the DOM like this: `$(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);`

Does it matter which way you store the data? I would personally cache `eventObject` in a JavaScript cache object (ie make your own cache class or a map). Isn't it simpler to cache like this than mess with the DOM and then you have to remember where you put what?

In my searches I've looked at [XML DOM vs Object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019781/xml-dom-vs-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Your #2 method is jQuery, not vanilla JavaScript. Under the hood, I believe it is stored in a cache object of sorts (you can look at the data() method in the jQuery source for more details).

Comment: Using jQuery data() at runtime will actually store all data in $.cache, so there's no real difference. You only gain another way of referencing your data.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't it simpler to cache like this than mess with the DOM and then you have to remember where you put what?

[jQuery's `data` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/) actually doesn't mess with the DOM, it is just a convenient way to reference data objects by DOM nodes.

Of course, if you "*have to remember whery you put it*" the DOM references are not the best way to reference your objects. If a simple cache object seems cleaner to you, it probably will be cleaner.